# Can't Register Devices On Azure Notification Hub Using Node.js Backend

Tags: cordova, push-notification, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to register a device using the Azure Mobile Services Node.js back end with the following code:

```js
var notificationHubService = azure.createNotificationHubService('<HubName>', '<Endpoint>');
var payload = {
    alert: 'Hello!'
};

function insert(item, user, request) {
    notificationHubService.createRegistrationId(function (error, registrationId, response) {
        if (!error) {
            notificationHubService.apns.createOrUpdateNativeRegistration(registrationId, item.Token, [item.id], function (error, response) {

                if (!error) {
                    console.log('Inside : createOrUpdateNativeRegistration' + response);
                    notificationHubService.apns.send(null, payload, function (error) {
                        if (!error) {
                            // notification sent

                            console.log('Success: Inside the notification send call to Hub.');

                        }
                    });

                }
                else {

                    console.log('Error in registering the device with Hub for Token: ' + item.Token + '>> ' + error);
                }

            });

        }
        else {
            console.log('Error in generating the registration Id' + error);
        }

    });
    request.execute();   
 }
```

But I keep receiving the following error:

*EDIT:* This line is causing the error:

```js
notificationHubService.apns.createOrUpdateNativeRegistration
```

```js
 Error: 400 - One or more characters in device token is not a hexadecimal
```

The token is generated using the https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/PushNotification cordova plugin on the client which results in the following token:

```js
APA91bGiwjCSslyOjqIP4Cerf5LJFkDYAyVHpT0GdIEQ81z9LJMGkUAV0ScgL9ioOqL38ZFTuFHwQRP389OAOPcOGxp2MZHBbYR6BlL70xIW8jHU1ZsJIdtUoww1mCx4cWqmZzjErZDz
```

I have also attempted to generate the token using the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push cordova plugin on the client which results in the following token:

```js
cF3dKfF5j14:APA91bEruizX883Aegix-UPyQHjCgyl1ZfoXoFQUhf3JH_A8W_iITk-SyEsBjnnWlvTgAONEspAkTpy8IonqvL0bYFGGm9jDj-Kbjf3bF_T0LFiQ2fUQIHcP1uHsiby3AcGi-dlL6aP6
```

Both tokens result in the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would  ask the Telerik push plugin developers how comes they have another token format, i.e. their token has no dashes in between. The token is provided by either FCM, APNS, or WNS and the format cannot vary from plugin to plugin.

I would only the ID from the **phonegap-plugin-push**. The FCM token I regularly receive with this plugin is in this format:

```
eb1-bYqMrQ8:APC97bHXxUTb_dbAK255ew4uvBR8gRDo-1_9RyEX_Be6WiRAy3qS5f1bIEWT2e8FtIBbWj_0x1ep2uo7H8TOG0hGc4Be4hBdx1VPcwn_Mrfbo8NscxjMJZfCZRLbGCE_mGPK_-1_rgh3
```

I remember I had some problems because when I sent the registrationID, it was being altered by the AJAX request (missing dashes or something of the sort), so you must triple-check to compare the ID you are receiving and the one you sending to Azure.